# Add class to HTML rows with jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table in HTML that I need to modify by using jQuery specifically. I need to apply 'header' class to main row and 'even' and 'odd' classes to the other rows in consecutive order.

As a result, the table will have a blue main header and light grey background row in each consecutive row. How can I achieve this? I have CSS already, just need to figure out how to grab these row and add the classes. You can see my attempts in attached .js file. What am I doing wrong?

```js
"use strict";

// this JS file will call the plugin when the page loads

$(document).ready(function() {
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
"use strict";
// this is where jQuery goes

$(function(){
 $('#important tr:first-child').addClass('header');

  $("#important tr:not(header)").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass((index % 2) ? "even" : "odd");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Alternating Row Plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="altrow.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.altrow.js"></script>
    <script src="altrow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
      <h1>Important People in Computer Science</h1>
      <table id="important">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Accomplishment</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charles</td><td>Babbage</td><td>12/26/1791</td>
                <td>Originated the concept of a programmable computer, invented the first mechanical computer.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ada</td><td>Lovelace</td><td>12/10/1815</td>
                <td>First computer programmer. Wrote an algorithm for Babbage's mechanical computer.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alan</td><td>Turing</td><td>6/23/1912</td>
                <td>Invented the Turing Machine, a hypothetical device that's a model of a general purpose computer.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Grace</td><td>Hopper</td><td>12/9/1906</td>
                <td>Invented the first compiler for a computer programming language, popularized the term "debugging" for fixing computer glitches.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `<thead>` for header, then the rest can be done with css `tr:nth-child(even){...}`, no js needed

Comment: addcass should be addClass

Comment: I have edited and updated your code from `addcass` to `addClass`. now put your code that adds class `header` to first `<tr>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am forced to use jQuery for this. @LawrenceCherone

Comment: np, reminds me of [Add a number to another number in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694603/add-a-number-to-another-number-in-javascript) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, you do not need Javascript, you can solve this with CSS. However, since your question specifically asked for Javascript, I will provide JS solutions for you. First, let's fix your typo:

```
$('#important tr:first-child').addClass('header');
```

Note the capital `C` above.

Just below the line above, do something like this

```
$("#important tr:not(header)").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass((index % 2) ? "even" : "odd");
});
```

Full solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Alternating Row Plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="altrow.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.altrow.js"></script>
    <script src="altrow.js"></script>
    <style>
        .even {
            background-color: lightgray;
        }
        .odd {
            background-color: darkgray;
        }
        .header {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#important tr:first-child').addClass('header');
            $("#important tr:not(.header)").each(function(index) {
                $(this).addClass((index % 2) ? "even" : "odd");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
      <h1>Important People in Computer Science</h1>
      <table id="important">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Accomplishment</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charles</td><td>Babbage</td><td>12/26/1791</td>
                <td>Originated the concept of a programmable computer, invented the first mechanical computer.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ada</td><td>Lovelace</td><td>12/10/1815</td>
                <td>First computer programmer. Wrote an algorithm for Babbage's mechanical computer.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alan</td><td>Turing</td><td>6/23/1912</td>
                <td>Invented the Turing Machine, a hypothetical device that's a model of a general purpose computer.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Grace</td><td>Hopper</td><td>12/9/1906</td>
                <td>Invented the first compiler for a computer programming language, popularized the term "debugging" for fixing computer glitches.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it, and the table rows changed color. But my header is still blank (it should be light blue). Here is my .js:

`"use strict";

$(function(){
 $('#important tr:first-child').addClass('header');

  $("#important tr:not(header)").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass((index % 2) ? "even" : "odd");
  });
});`

Comment: Sorry I can't find a way to do line breaks in stack overflow comment code blocks.

Comment: I updated the .js code above with my latest version.

Comment: @dot-combubble can you create a JSFiddle or a snippet where the exact code you use is present and the problem is reproducible? I suppose there is a typo or something that does not help you. So, if you create a reproducible example, preferably in a fiddle, then I will probably solve it for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=lDnl7G7Bb2 but I can't add my second .js file which will call the jQuery on startup.

Comment: @dot-combubble I arrive at an empty fiddle. Can we do it without toghetherjs?

Comment: Ok, I could see you but something broke down. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/xLq8nw2y/1/

Comment: I think what happens is that only one $(function() {}) gets executed and that's why I can either format the header or the rows. But I need to format both of them.

Comment: @dot-combubble there were two problems, the first committed by you and the second committed by me. Both were typos. 1. You need an https instead of an http when you link jquery from cdn into JSFiddle. 2. I should have written a `.` to notify the class into the selector. See: https://jsfiddle.net/68mjwe2d/

Comment: @dot-combubble fixed this inside my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it. Let me update the code in my question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript for this simple task, you can target `even` or `odd`elements via CSS:

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(even)  {
  background-color: pink;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd)  {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Important People in Computer Science</h1>
  <table id="important">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
        <th>Accomplishment</th>
      </tr>
      <thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Charles</td>
            <td>Babbage</td>
            <td>12/26/1791</td>
            <td>Originated the concept of a programmable computer, invented the first mechanical computer.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ada</td>
            <td>Lovelace</td>
            <td>12/10/1815</td>
            <td>First computer programmer. Wrote an algorithm for Babbage's mechanical computer.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Alan</td>
            <td>Turing</td>
            <td>6/23/1912</td>
            <td>Invented the Turing Machine, a hypothetical device that's a model of a general purpose computer.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Grace</td>
            <td>Hopper</td>
            <td>12/9/1906</td>
            <td>Invented the first compiler for a computer programming language, popularized the term "debugging" for fixing computer glitches.</td>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use jQuery for this project, so that's my only way.

Comment: So you can't write any CSS in this project?

Comment: CSS is already written and it will do the coloring after I add relevant classes with jQuery.

Comment: So it's easir to implement a javascript solution instead of renaming your class from `.even` to `tr:nth-child(even) ` ? But if that's the requirement, then you will have to use one of the other answers, just wanted to point out that no JS is needed for this.